# How to remove a permission, a member, or a role?

Tags: powershell, ssas

I have this script below to add roles and members and permissions

```
Import-Module sqlserver
$Server = new-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server
$Server.Connect("SERVER\INSTANCE")

$TabDB = $SERVER.Databases["DATABASENAME"]
$AddRole = new-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ModelRole
$AddRole.Name = 'NewRole1'
$AddRole.ModelPermission="Read"
$RoleMember = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.WindowsModelRoleMember
$RoleMember.MemberName = 'DOMAIN\ACCOUNT'
$TabDB.Model.Roles.Add($AddRole)
$AddRole.Members.Add($RoleMember)
$TabDB.Update([Microsoft.AnalysisServices.UpdateOptions]::ExpandFull)
$server.Disconnect()
```

How can I remove a permission, a member, and a role?

I tried this at least for the role, but the console returns back "False"

```
$TabDB.Model.Roles.Remove($AddRole)
```

Comment: Where in the script did you run `remove()`

Comment: @ArcSet instead of Add, i used remove. i pasted the script with the Add because the tabular structure is complex so anyone looking at this post would have some idea how adding would work, so removing would be similar. i didnt want to change the Add to remove in this script here because it would not provide for anyone reading this a clue how tabular works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with ssas from powershell (or C# for that matter) you can use the `analysisservices` namespace of microsoft:
[Microsoft analysisservices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices?view=analysisservices-dotnet).

This is an object oriented way of working with ssas databases.

This is an old script I wrote for maintainers:

```
function addRoleToDb {
  $roleName = Read-Host "How should this role be called?"
  if ($global:dataBase.Roles.findByName($roleName)) {
    echo "This role already exists"
    return
  } elseif ($roleName -eq "") {
    echo "You can't give an empty name for a role."
    return
  }
  echo "Warning: this role will start out empty and will have to be modified in order to be used. (it wil have read permission)"
  [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Role] $newRole = New-Object([Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Role])($roleName)
  $global:dataBase.Roles.add($newRole)
  $dbperm = $global:dataBase.DatabasePermissions.add($newRole.ID)
  $dbperm.Read = [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ReadAccess]::Allowed
  $global:dataBase.Roles.Update()
  $dbperm.Update()
  return
}
```

At this point I already had a global variable database. 
This is a method that would add a role to the database. Deleting the database would work practically the same, you would get the instance of the role with:

```
role = database.roles.findbyname()
```

or

```
role = database.roles.findbyid()
```

and then

```
role.Drop(DropOptions.AlterOrDeleteDependents);
```

You should check that last line before using it because the `alterordeletedependants` is something I now use in my c# program, I don't remember if it worked in powershell.

Good luck!